# using awk to split a large file

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
##DATA
##D=H|<...>|<...>|...
...
H|233|AAPL|US|1389593.1533|
A|1|113581395.1353|524532||525|1541|a|19191|1919
E|2|413581395.1353|123332||525|1541|c|15333|1533
...
H|233|TSLA|US|133.1533|
A|1|13538815.1353|524532||525|6466|a|686|123
E|2|76976978.1353|123332||525|2343|d|6968|697
...
```

I want split this file by stocks, e.g. `AAPL.txt`, and `TSLA.txt`, and create a separate text file with messages for each stock.

I tried using `awk` to get all the lines that start with `H` and get the stock symbol:

```
awk -F"|" `/^H/ {print $3}' input.txt
```

but I'm not sure how to get all the messages for each stock.

Comment: Can I assume the 1st line of the block (to be separated to individual file) start with `H` followed by a `|` character?

Comment: `awk -F"|" '/^H/{close(var);var=$3".txt"}{print > var}' file`

Comment: @tshiono yes, that is correct

Comment: @HatLess I get an error: `awk: cannot open "" for output (No such file or directory)`

Comment: I would write `if (var) close(var)`, but HatLess's answer should work. @MoneyBall what awk version are you using?

Comment: @glennjackman I am using `mawk 1.3.4 20200120`

Comment: OK, you changed the input file, no fair ;) -- to ignore the header stuff, only print if the `var` variable is not empty: `/^H/ {close(var); var=$3".txt"} var {print > var}'`

Comment: @glennjackman Aha! I guessed that it had to be due to the header stuff so I added them. I should've done that earlier. It worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @glennjackman sorry for asking another question but is there a way to use a variable defined before `awk` call insdie `awk`? For instance, I have a `dir_path` variable. I want to do `/^H/ {close(var); var=$dir_path"/"$3".txt"} var {print > var}'` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have added an answer addressing the additional condition

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F"|" -v path="/path/to/file/" '/^H/ { close(var); var=path$3".txt" } var { print > var }' file
```

or if a variable to the path already exist

```
$ awk -F"|" -v path="$variable" '/^H/ { close(var); var=path$3".txt" } var {print > var}' file
```

Comment: You may also want a rule to skip comments or the first two lines. Along with ensuring whether the `^A` and `^E` lines are needed (or all lines to the next `^H`). I don't know, that's not clear from the question -- but worth clarifying.

Comment: I find the no-whitespace style hard to read.

Comment: if the shell variable $variable lacks a trailing "/", i think the 2nd solution you listed might concat the deepest directory name with the stock symbols, and create files at the 2nd-deepest level instead, i.e. /path/to/fileAAPL.txt

Answer (score -4):

UPDATE :

auto-handling of `dir_path` shell variable, defaulting to current folder if not found, plus basic amount of data cleansing.

advantage of this design is all rows for each stock gets printed in one shot, saving time from excessive pattern evaluation

```
close()^0th-power
```

is to ensure, regardless of whether it's the first time executing the logic, i.e. nothing to close yet, or subsequent stocks, `1` always get returned from that part, thus guaranteeing it'll correctly fetch stock symbol from `$2`

`0-th power` avoids having to do manually handle all the different cases of its return value - from `-1` to `255`

(it's `$2` not `$3` in my design because I've used the leading `H|` pattern in `RS` instead).

I decided against a `/^H/` approach because something like `Hello|` would inadvertently match, even though it's clearly invalid/data error.

```
rm  AAPL.txt TSLA.txt; 
echo "${aa}" \
             | gawk -e '

BEGIN { 
     dir_path=ENVIRON[\
              ( ("dir_path" in ENVIRON) ? "dir_path" \ 
              : ( "PWD"     in ENVIRON) ? "PWD" : "./" ) ]
     
       gsub(/[/]+/,"/", dir_path)
       sub(/[/]$/,"/",  dir_path)
     gsub(/\000/, "",   dir_path)

      ___=index(RS="\012"(_="H")\
               (FS="["(____="|")"]"),_)
        _=(_)____
 
 } !/^\43\43/ {  # auto-skipping comment block
 
  print \
    (_)$(_<_) > (__=(dir_path)($(___^close(__)^_))".txt") }'

ls -lrt | gtail -n 2 | lgp3 ; cat AAPL.txt| ecp; cat TSLA.txt


-rw-r--r--     1 staff         126 Apr 13 05:13 AAPL.txt
-rw-r--r--     1 staff         116 Apr 13 05:13 TSLA.txt

 
H|233|AAPL|US|1389593.1533|
A|1|113581395.1353|524532||525|1541|a|19191|1919
E|2|413581395.1353|123332||525|1541|c|15333|1533
 
H|233|TSLA|US|133.1533|
A|1|13538815.1353|524532||525|6466|a|686|123
E|2|76976978.1353|123332||525|2343|d|6968|697
```